# Fill up string length with random character

Tags: java, for-loop, random

This is my random fill up code, base on the loop, it should generate 4 random char after "KELVIN"(because KELVIN takes 6 char), but when i print, only generate 2 random char, strange

```
   Random r = new Random();
            //string imported  
            String word = "KELVIN";

            //loop for fill up 10 characters
            for (int i=0; i<10-word.length();i++)
            {
               char randomadd = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
               word +=randomadd;
            }

        System.out.print(word+"==");
```

Console output:

```
KELVINSN==
```

Comment: Your condition in the `for` loop uses `word.length()`, which increases with each iteration.

Comment: You should look into using a StringBuilder instead of adding characters to the String each time.

Comment: thanks guys, i see, i will try that StringBuilder, but i think method from @rgettman more easier

Comment: @atom2ueki I recommend getting my solution to work first, then attempting to use `StringBuilder` as trevor-e suggests.  `StringBuilder` is more efficient at constructing strings than repeatedly using `+=` to concatenate strings.

Comment: @rgettman your suggestion works,i go to try [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each loop, you affect the length of the word.  The effect is that you only add half the characters necessary to bring the word length up to 10.

First iteration.  `i` is 0.  The condition `i < 10 - 6` is `true`, so a random character is added.

Second iteration.  `i` is 1, but the word length is now 7.  `i < 10 - 7` is `true`, so a second random character is added.

Now `i` is 2, but the word length is now 8.  `i < 10 - 8` is `false`, so the loop ends.

The solution is to pre-determine the number of characters needed, so it doesn't change each iteration:

```
int charsNeeded = 10 - word.length();
for (int i = 0; i < charsNeeded; i++)
```